# Boost Compute buffer deconstructor behaving differently on different OS

Tags: c++, opencl, boost-compute

I'm having an issue with a bit of boost compute code that I have running on two machines.  My dev machine is running windows 7 using a radeon WX9100 gpu, and everything is running fine.  Another lab machine I am using is nearly identical, but is running windows 10 and has the windows 10 version of the radeon driver.

The windows 7 machine shows the openCL device name being "GFX900" and the windows 10 machine shows the name as "GFX901".  A bitcoin mining site i found said this is fine for that model.

What is not fine is that the boost compute/opencl memory buffers do not free from device memory on the windows 10 machine, even (especially) if i use "BUFFERNAME.~buffer()".

Im thinking this might be a driver issue, but I'm really not sure.

Thanks in advance for any help!
Eric

Comment: How are you determining that they are not being freed? But yes, it sounds like you need to get in touch with AMD's developer support or ask on [their OpenCL forum](https://community.amd.com/community/devgurus/opencl).

Comment: @pmdj I was able to tell they are not being freed because the windows 10 resource manager lets me view the memory usage of the GPU.  When the usage goes above 16gb the application consistently crashes because their is only 16 gigs of memory.  Ill post this question on that forum. Thanks!

Comment: Which Boost.Compute version do you use?